# Creating a cross-sdk wrapper for Firebase (Firestore, Cloud Storage, and more)

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to find an abstraction that can allow me to run Firebase products (mainly Firestore, Storage, and Analytics) regardless of the platform (React Native, React, Node.js). I have looked at the REST API but would like to use the SDKs for all the features that they offer.

```
// web
import firebase from 'firebase';
type WebFirestore = ReturnType<typeof firebase.firestore>;

// cloud
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
type CloudFirestore = ReturnType<typeof admin.firestore>;

// native
import { FirebaseFirestoreTypes } from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
type NativeFirestore = FirebaseFirestoreTypes.Module;

const API = (firestore: WebFirestore | CloudFirestore | NativeFirestore) => {
  firestore
    .collection('foo')
    .doc('foo')
    .get()
    .then((resp) => true);
}
```

I'm trying to create a TypeScript type that can enable me to do the same (at least that's what I think). The API, on the outset, is kept consistent across platforms for these products but my guess is that the return types are different. By that I mean, I can run this function on all platforms as long as the firestore object belongs to the SDK on that platform.

I was thinking of creating a class that takes a flag ('web', 'cloud', 'native') and then also take the firestore object in the constructor. I tried running the code below but TypeScript says the following:

```
(property) Promise<T>.then: (<TResult1 = FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult1 = firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot<...>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot<...>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult1 = FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<...>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<...>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>)
Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.

@param onfulfilled — The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.

@param onrejected — The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.

@returns — A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.

This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<TResult1 = DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult1 = DocumentSnapshot<...>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: DocumentSnapsh...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

I'm rather new to TypeScript and was wondering if there is a way to make this work. All the types individually work but their union doesn't work. Is there a better way to think about this layer of abstraction in TypeScript? I intend to host this on the Github package registry and all the products to have access to the internal API as functions that are currently - firestore, cloud storage, cloud functions, some REST API calls.

Comment: the TypeScript error shows at .then(...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switching based on `string` flag is almost never the "right" way.  You want to replace `if` conditions with a level of abstraction.

#### Adapter Pattern

You might want to read up on the [Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), which is a generalized OOP approach to this sort of situation.  Instead of one class with `type` property, you would have a separate wrapper class for each type of store instance.  These classes would all have the same public API `interface SharedFirestore`, but internally they could call different methods on their `this.firestore` to get the results.  When you want to use a firestore, you would just require the type `SharedFirestore` and you would know that you could interact with it the same regardless of which store type it is.

That sort of setup looks like:

```
interface SharedFirestore {
  getDoc( collectionPath: string, documentPath: string ): Document;
}

class WebFirestore implements SharedFirestore {
  
  private firestore: firebase.firestore.Firestore;

  constructor( app?: firebase.app.App ) {
    this.firestore = firebase.firestore(app);
  }

  getDoc( collectionPath: string, documentPath: string ): Document {
    return this.firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc(documentPath);
  }
}

class CloudFirestore implements SharedFirestore {

  private firestore: FirebaseFirestore.Firestore;

  constructor( app?: admin.app.App ) {
    this.firestore = admin.firestore(app);
  }

  getDoc( collectionPath: string, documentPath: string ): Document {
    return this.firestore.someOtherMethod( collectionPath, documentPath );
  }
}
```

#### Typescript Generics

Wrapper classes are not necessary here because the three types *already* implement the same interface, kind of.  They all allow you to get a document by calling `firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc(documentPath).get()`.  This is purely a typescript issue which is caused by the differing return types.

```
web.collection('foo').doc('foo').get();
// type: firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>

cloud.collection('foo').doc('foo').get();
// type: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>

native.collection('foo').doc('foo').get();
// type: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData>
```

Your `then` callback is a function of the document, but you don't know which of the three types of document you have.  So you cannot call a function on the union.  Instead we need to say "whichever type of store I have, my callback will match that".  To do that, we make the `API` a generic which depends on the store type.

We can use some conditional types to extract the associated types for the collection and the document from the store type.

```
interface BaseCollection<D> {
  doc(path: string): D;
}

interface BaseStore<C extends BaseCollection<any>> {
  collection(path: string): C;
}

type CollectionFromStore<S> = S extends BaseStore<infer C> ? C : never;

type DocFromCollection<C> = C extends BaseCollection<infer D> ? D : never;

type DocFromStore<S> = DocFromCollection<CollectionFromStore<S>>
```

Here's a possible setup that uses generics to extend a base type rather than extending a union.

```
class FirebaseAPI <S extends BaseStore<any>> {
  
constructor( private firebase: S ) {}

  getCollection( collectionPath: string ): CollectionFromStore<S> {
    return this.firebase.collection(collectionPath);
  }

  getDoc( collectionPath: string, documentPath: string ): DocFromStore<S> {
    return this.getCollection(collectionPath).doc(documentPath);
  }
}
```

You can see how we get the appropriate return types.

```
(new FirebaseAPI(web)).getDoc('', '').get().then(v => {});
// v has type firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot<firebase.firestore.DocumentData>
(new FirebaseAPI(cloud)).getDoc('', '').get().then(v => {});
// v has type FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>
(new FirebaseAPI(native)).getDoc('', '').get().then(v => {});
// v has type FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentSnapshot<FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData>
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/aNnOBm)